# alert dialog unable to close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran the following code in Google Chrome Version 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit). It displays an alert dialog successively asking for input until the user enters the correct answer, but the problem is that when i click the close button or cancel button in the alert dialog instead of closing, it continues asking for input.Also the close button on the tab is unclickable.Nevertheless I can close chrome main window but is there a code to correct this.

```
var answer = Number(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));

do{
    var number = Number(prompt("Guess a number"));
    if(number-answer >10){
        alert("Too big!!");
    }
    else if(number-answer < 10 && number>answer ){
        alert("It's bigger, but you are close!");
    }
    else if(answer-number < 10 && number<answer){
        alert("It's smaller, but you are close!");
    }
    else if(answer-number > 10){
        alert("Too small!!");
    }
    else if(number==answer){
    alert("You WIN !!");
    break;
    }
}while(number!=answer);
```

Comment: your code is under do while hence unless "You Win" alert is displayed this will go on

Comment: There is one place where you report number-answer >10 is too big, and another where it is too small. Just thought I would let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and straightforward answer would be to remove the `do...while` loop. 'coz that would keep the code running till you input the right answer.

So, you could check for the inputed number, if it is null break it, else convert it to your number and run the loop.

checking for `null` firsthand would make it easy to check for 0 as an input too

```
var answer = Number(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));

do{
    var number = prompt("Guess a number");
    if(number!=null){
        number = Number(number);
    } else {
        break;
    }
    if(number-answer >10){
        alert("Too big!!");
    }
    else if(number-answer < 10 && number>answer ){
        alert("It's bigger, but you are close!");
    }
    else if(answer-number < 10 && number<answer){
        alert("It's smaller, but you are close!");
    }
    else if(answer-number > 10){
        alert("Too small!!");
    }
    else if(number==answer){
    alert("You WIN !!");
    break;
    }
}while(number!=answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var answer = Number(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));

do{
    var number = Number(prompt("Guess a number"));
    if(number === 0){ // this check is needed
        break;
    }

    if(number-answer >10){
        alert("Too big!!");
    }
    else if(number-answer < 10 && number>answer ){
        alert("It's bigger, but you are close!");
    }
    else if(answer-number < 10 && number<answer){
        alert("It's smaller, but you are close!");
    }
    else if(answer-number > 10){
        alert("Too small!!");
    }
    else if(number==answer){
    alert("You WIN !!");
    break;
    }
}while(number!=answer);
```

on closing the prompt, null is returned

passing null to Number function will return 0

hence the check for 0 is added

you could also modify the code as follows to allow 0 as input from the user

```
var input= prompt("Guess a number");
if(input === null){
  break;
}

var number = Number(input);
    ... rest of the code
```

Answer (score 1):

If click `cancel`, the input value will be `null`, then `Number(null)` will be `0`.Unless the guess number is `0`, the alert dialog would not be closed.

You'd better check the input value is `null` before cast it.

[Window.prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

Answer (score 0):

I have added a line of code to check whether user has cancelled the prompt.

```
var answer = Number(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));

do{
    var number = Number(prompt("Guess a number"));

    // Add the below code to check for null and exit

    if (number === null)break;

    // END

    if(number-answer >10){
        alert("Too big!!");
    }
    else if(number-answer < 10 && number>answer ){
        alert("It's bigger, but you are close!");
    }
    else if(answer-number < 10 && number<answer){
        alert("It's smaller, but you are close!");
    }
    else if(answer-number > 10){
        alert("Too small!!");
    }
    else if(number==answer){
    alert("You WIN !!");
    break;
    }
}while(number!=answer);
```